# What's the difference between esc_* functions?

Tags: security, escaping, sanitization

I've read *Professional WordPress* and it says:

> `esc_html` function is used for
>   scrubbing data that contains HTML.
>   This function encodes special
>   characters into their HTML entities
>
> `esc_attr` function is used for escaping
>   HTML attributes
>
> `esc_url`. This function should be used
>   to scrub the URL for illegal
>   characters. Even though the href is
>   technically an HTML attribute

What's the difference between these?

If I have

```
<script>alert('hello world!');</script>this is some content
```

Would all `< >` be converted to `&lt; &gt;`? Will the URL be something like `%xxx`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`esc_html` and `esc_attr` are near-identical, the only difference is that output gets passed through differently named filters ( `esc_html` and `attribute_escape` respectively).

`esc_url` is more complex and specific, it deals with characters that can't be in URLs and allowed protocols (list of which can be passed as second argument). It will also prepend input with `http://` protocol if it's not present (and link is not relative).